# Check to see if site is online, limit the timeout

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a function that checks if a site is online or not, but is having some problem with the timeout. I want to limit it to a max 3 sec, if there is no respons within 3 sec I should see the page as offline.

My try:

```
class OnlineCheck
    {
        public static bool IsOnline(string url)
        {
            try
            {
                WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
                webclient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.KeepAlive, "1000");

                webclient.OpenRead(url);
            }
            catch { return false; }

            return true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The WebClient doesn't support timeout. But you can use the HttpWebRequest!

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Endpoint);
request.Timeout=3000;
request.GetResponse();
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to check that the site is online, you are not really interested in the content of the page, just that you get a response. To make that more efficient, you should only request the http headers. Here is a quick example on how you could do:

```
private static IEnumerable<HttpStatusCode> onlineStatusCodes = new[]
{
    HttpStatusCode.Accepted,
    HttpStatusCode.Found,
    HttpStatusCode.OK,
    // add more codes as needed
};

private static bool IsSiteOnline(string url, int timeout)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
    {
        if (request != null)
        {
            request.Method = "HEAD"; // get headers only
            request.Timeout = timeout;
            using (var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                return response != null && onlineStatusCodes.Contains(response.StatusCode);
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use HttpWebRequest rather than WebClient. HttpWebRequest class has a timeout property.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
        System.Net.WebRequest r = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
        r.Timeout = 3000;

        System.Net.WebProxy proxy = new System.Net.WebProxy("<proxy address>");
        System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();

        credentials.Domain = "<domain>";
        credentials.UserName = "<login>";
        credentials.Password = "<pass>";

        proxy.Credentials = credentials;
        r.Proxy = proxy;

        try
        {
            System.Net.WebResponse rsp = r.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Is not avaliable");
            return;
        }

        MessageBox.Show("Avaliable!");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static bool isOnline (string URL)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
    request.Timeout = 3000;

    try
    {
        WebResponse resp = request.GetResponse();
    }
    catch (WebException e)
    {
        if (((HttpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```